Paladin/Warlock Multiclass
I am playing a Leonin Paladin/2 and thinking of multiclassing into Warlock. Just wondering if A. if it is a good idea B. what Patron would work best C. if I should how many levels should I put in?

You haven't told us what your goals are or what you're trying to optimize for, or other things about your Paladin class.  For example, if you are trying to optimize for the best RP experience, we would have almost nothing to go on.

Welcome to the stack Urmgurm0114!  Take the tour when you have a moment, and feel free to peruse the help center for more in-depth info about the site.

It can work OK
First off, what is useful to you will depend on your specific goals for your character. But there are a few general observations I can relate from experience that may be useful to you.
In my play group, one of the players has done exactly what you consider, starting from paladin 2 into a paladin/warlock mix (now paladin 2/warlock 2). Here are some synergies:

Paladins typically already have a high Charisma, which is the second highest recommended ability after high Strength for the Paladin "Quick Build", and needed anyways for Paladin Spellcasting. You can reuse the high ability score for your Warlock spellcasting.
The warlock class gives you extra spell slots and more every short rest, that you can also use with the paladin to Divine Smite.
He picked a Hexblade warlock as the subclass, to keep with the theme of melee combat abilities. This gives access to the shield spell, which when combined with the armor can get you ridiculously high AC when it matters at these levels1; Green Flame Blade, if available, can also be a useful cantrip for melee, and Hexblade's Curse is a good use for your bonus action.
Warlocks also get Eldritch Blast as a cantrip, the best damage cantrip in the game. It can help you shore up your ranged combat, when you are Strength based for melee combat, which many Paladins are to make most of the ability to wear heavy armor, and you as a Leonin with +1 to Strength almost assuredly are.

Obviously, there are also real downsides to the choice of early multiclassing out of Paladin, the most glaring ones are that you are delaying or will never get access to your Sacred Oath as a Paladin at level 3, you will delay access to the important Ability Score Improvment at level 4, and you also will not get to the all-important Extra Attack at level 5. And at higher levels, the relatively fewer spell slots that a warlock has will used up faster if you spend them on shield, compared to for example a sorcerer as another Charisma-based caster that could also complement a paladin with extra slots.
So in the end, this is an OK multiclass, but you could just as well just continue as paladin. It is more a question of how you envision your character, and what would be more fun to play, than an optimization issue.

1 With plain chaimail for AC 16, Defensive Fighting Style for +1, a shield for +2, shield of faith for +2, and shield spell, you get to AC 26 at level 3. Few enemies at that level of play can hit that outside of a critical. Once you can upgrade to full plate, AC 28 is even tougher.

Nothing is bad about what you want to do.
First, you're fine with ability scores as both paladins and warlocks want to have good CHARISMA. This is a common multiclass that many have done before.
Second, there aren't any wrong choices for patrons, just decide which options look like the most fun, and what you want your character to be good at.
Third, warlocks get most of their features in the first 2 or 3 levels (invocations, and pact boons), so it's probably best to go at least 2 levels into warlock, but after that it just depends on preferences.
Last, remember that this is a role playing game and there is no "wrong way" to play, just decide what is fun for you and work with your DM to make that happen for you and your character.
